# AWS Load balancer in front of k8s master

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-elb

I have a k8s cluster (1 master node) that was spun up in private subnet. I want to set up an AWS load balancer in order to use `kubectl` from the internet. I tried setting up network load balancer but it didn't work. Anyone suggests me an approach to achieve that goal, please.

Answer (score 2):

A load balancer will not help you use `kubectl` to manage kubernetes.

You either need a public IP or a VPN setup within your VPC. Consider using OpenVPN to allow your kubectl running on your desktop to connect to Kubernetes.

Comment: I was considering OpenVPN, but it's not a convenient way. Why does load balancer not help in this case?

Comment: Why do you think that it might help?
Another thing could be an SSH tunnel. But the best way is, as John described, an OpenVPN tunnel. You could go the easy way and just place a RaspberryPi with pivpn. Easy to setup and you'll be in your network.